# Using {{field}} as a parameter in Tempo (JavaScript/JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, datatemplate, function-parameter, tempo

Is it possible to use {{field}} as a parameter of a javascript function using [Tempo](http://twigkit.github.com/tempo/)?

Something like,

```
<ol id="marx-brothers">
    <li data-template>{% getAge({{born}}) %}</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the documentation on Tempo.  There is nothing there that suggests it can call a function while populating a template.  If you need getAge called you have to do it before running the template in tempo.

```
<ol id="marx-brothers">
    <li data-template>{{getAgeResults}}</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's true, I misunderstood the tag blocks. What JavaScript template would you recommend to use with JSON?